# Query for posts from any post type but only add instock products

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic

I need build a query like these :
Fetch 10 posts from any post_type but if the post_type was product then only add it if it is `instock`.
When i use meta_query for this purpose it only returns products ! because that meta is not available on other posts.
What can i do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes - if your `instock` data is a meta field, adding that condition as a meta query will only return items that have that value in that field.

Comment: You can use pre_get_posts to add the special query for the product. If you use the post_status : publish and set woocommerce options to hide if the product has no stock, it can work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check status `instock` only if meta key `_stock_status` exists.

Something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'instock',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_stock_status',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
        )
```

Note: Code is not tried or tested, so check for any syntax errors

Comment: Thank you so much, your snippet works fine and resolved my problem. I was really going to use what others mentioned but you saved my life.